# why <link type="text/css" src="html content"> not working

Tags: html

I want to convert html content to css content using the Tag Link's Attribute type="text", but it does not work!

1. Here is my php code:

```php
//url with (http://127.0.0.1/test.php);
//I know it should be: header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo "BODY{background-color:#f00;}"
```

2. html code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- 
            it not works!why?
            I've pointed that type="text/css"
            why it can't be convert to text/css
         -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/test.php">
    </head>
    <body>
        anything ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**why attrbute type for tag link not works?**
**But the script Tag works well!**

My english is very poor, if you can't understand my words, please leave me a message! Thanks for your answers！

---

**SUMMERY**
@Luke Briggs's answer helps me to understand why sometime works or not！
@Dekel's answer helps me to understand @Luke Briggs's answer
thks a lot!

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? I recommend to to add some content to the body, e.g. `<body>Some Content</body>`.

Comment: this just my sample code,I've tested!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Content-type: text/css` and not `text/html`:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
echo "body {background-color:#f00;}";
```

The reason for your current code to **not work** is that the browser is trying to get a resource and parse it, but the server tells the browser that the resource's content is `text/html`. Because the server tells the browser that the content is `HTML` - the browser will not try to use that content as CSS.

Comment: Did u see my php 's Commented code！It's not my questions

Comment: `//I know it should be: header("Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8");` His words

Comment: @AliRasheed, thanks for the comment. Added an explanation regarding this.

Comment: @Carson, perhaps I didn't understand the question correctly. Sorry. Please let me know if the current explanation is better.

Comment: I want to use link's attribute type to do it! type="text/CSS"!thanks for yours answer!

Comment: It's not enough, because the browser will look at the `header` he got from the server

Comment: On which browser?

Comment: well, basically browsers should not run the script/css, because the origin source told the browser that it's **not** script/css. If the browser decides to do something different - it's up to the browser. You can't force the browser to use do this using attribute in the html.

Comment: @Dekel that's not strictly how it works. The type attribute is defined very differently in the spec on a `script` tag compared to on a `link` tag; I'll add some extra info to my answer.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, good answer, you got my vote there. However - in both cases the browser doesn't have to use the value inside the `type` attribute :), which is basically what exists in my answer. You can't force the browser using the `type` attribute.

Comment: Not completely true. Try the following: `header('Content-type: image/png'); echo "alert(1);";` with a `type="text/javascript"` in the `script` tag :)

Comment: On the above comment (which was discussed on my answer) - I get the alert in all 3 major browsers, except it seems that an unknown variant of Chrome blocks the image mime type likely due to an exploit; they're following the spec correctly.

Comment: your's answer were right,but his quote helps  me know why sometimes work or not work! but only one can accept,so ...

Comment: you can complete  yours answer,I want others can get the key words quickly

Answer (score 1):

The `type` attribute of a link tag is **"purely advisory"** as stated in the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element):

> User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the type attribute to determine its actual type.

Link tags describe a variety of things and not just CSS - a user agent uses that type attribute to know immediately if it supports the file or not:

> The type attribute is used as a hint to user agents so that they can avoid fetching resources they do not support.

In short, it's only there as a hint. The header coming from the server is the 'de-facto' type when used within a `link` tag.

## A real world example

In the source of a Twitter page you'll see this:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml" title="Twitter">
```

My ordinary web browser doesn't know what `application/opensearchdescription+xml` is, so it avoids loading that xml file entirely (and as a side note, if it did load the XML file, it wouldn't know what to do with it anyway).

## What about a script element? Why does it work with them?

`script` elements define their type attribute [very differently](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) in the HTML5 specification:

> The value of the {src} attribute must be a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces identifying a script resource *of the type given by the type attribute*

This time the type attribute is not simply a hint - it defines the actual type to use.

Comment: did u means,if browser can't understand ,The tag attribute will work,other ways it well not work?thanks for urs answer!

Comment: @Carson the Content-Type header will always be used as the type. The `type` attribute exists for uses like this: `<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="/opensearch.xml" title="Twitter">` (as seen in Twitters source) - my browser doesn't know what `application/opensear..` means, so it ignores it.

Comment: @LukeBriggs, the part of the `type` regarding the `script` tag in your anwer is not correct. You quote the `src` and you said afterward that `it is the actual type to use`, but they are different.

Comment: @Dekel reworded that last part to make it a little clearer (also edited the comment above with a better example).

Comment: Again - pay attention to the part you quote. It's the `src` you quote. Not the `type`.

Comment: "a script resource of the type **given by the type attribute**" - this is the key.

Comment: Yet again - it's only a hint. Check the last comment I gave you in my answer. Did you try to run that code?

Comment: @Dekel it doesn't state that in the specification (unless you know somewhere that does?). I would *imagine* your code above will vary from browser to browser (and out of curiosity I'll try it in a range of them).

Comment: My guess would be that the `text/html` will work for `text/javascript` in some of the browsers because we are talking about `text` (and not `image`), but again - it's not something you can force. You must provide the correct `header` in order for the browser to read it and behave like you want :)

Comment: @Dekel true; and there's many instances where browsers technically violate the specification in a case that makes no sense, or more likely, turned out to be a security hole.

Comment: Correct. And yet again - this is what I'm trying to say here. You can't *force* the browser to do something (like parse js/css code of a resource) if the resource send a different content-type.

Comment: @Dekel but what I'm saying is it's likely broader than that - i.e. according to the spec a Content-Type of some random value *should* still be treated like whatever the `type` attribute says (but maybe there's exclusions for images, because of a possible threat vector there).

Comment: IMHO, if a server sends information regarding a resource (that he provided) - he probably knows better then the browser (who is more likely vulnerable to user-code-injections) ;)

Comment: @Dekel My suspicion was right though: It does appear to vary from browser to browser. I agree with that last statement, but the spec is the spec (and it's presumably that way as a result of some historical factor).

Comment: Correct. My guess is that this is the way to read the spec: The value of the {src} attribute **must be a valid non-empty URL** potentially surrounded by spaces **identifying a script resource of the type** given by the type attribute, so basically - the `src` should be of the `type` you provided. If the `src` is not of that `type` - this is wrong (which is what happen in our case). You said that the type is `text/javascript`, but the `URL` is actually **not** `text/javascript`.

Comment: @Dekel That's not how the W3C specifications work (I should know - I read them all day ;) ); i.e. compare how the type attribute is defined in the link tag where it clearly states that `Content-Type` is to be used. I ran a variant of your code in Firefox and it does actually alert with `image/png` as the content type.

Comment: @Dekel Hmm, it alerts in Chrome/IE too - they're actually all correctly following the spec; which browser did you not get the alert in? Presumably Safari?

Comment: No. chrome :) didn't get the alert there (and got the alert when removed  that wrong header)

Comment: @Dekel Here's a paste of what I tried - the 3 majors followed the spec: http://pastebin.com/nzqRuvHE

Comment: In chrome I got 3 logs and 1 error: Refused to execute script from 'type=image%2Fpng' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable.

Comment: @Dekel in my case Chrome logs all 4 (see https://snag.gy/qLuXDJ.jpg) - either way, it proves my point that the `type` attrib does dictate it on those random MIME types, except apparently in some variants of Chrome (presumably because of some exploit on images).